# Should I scale my app by cloning immutable instances of a single deployment, or update all deployed instances?

Tags: web-services, server

My app is running a single instance on AWS EC2 for now and I don't expect it to require scaling till next month. By then I know I'll need to scale to at least one more server if not two.

I've read about [immutable infrastructure](http://blog.codeship.com/immutable-infrastructure/) and the philosophy behind it but I've also read the [counter-arguments](https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/06/23/immutable-infrastructure-practical-or-not/). So, which one should I go for?

Comment: Which one best meets your specific requirements?

Comment: if you are scaling your app, surely you will require multiple instances?

Comment: @EwanYes, I will definitely need multiple instances, that's for sure. My question is, what would be the best way to deploy code to these?